# Where is the actual savedInstanceState object in lifecycle method onCreate()?

Tags: android, oop, kotlin, android-lifecycle

Where is the object savedInstanceState instantiated? Shouldn't it say somewhere, something like this `val savedInstance = SavedInstanceState()`?

```
MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state  maybe the official doc can give you a clue of this question.

Comment: A `Bundle` is passed to you, you do not really need to know where or how it's instantiated. From what I've gathered the actual creation of `savedInstanceState` is in [`ActivityThread#callActivityOnSaveInstanceState`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#5329), which is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Sandi Thanks you are right, however I needed more information to actually find the expression > r.state = new Bundle() to really convince me. I wanted to see the code to believe it and the answer Enselic gave me did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is instantiated by platform code. More specifically, the main system component responsible for keeping track of Activity states of apps is [ActivityManagerService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4f868ed/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java). This component forwards information about `savedInstanceState` to the appropriate application processes.

Once the app process have this information, it runs local code to manage e.g. `savedInstanceState`.  If you set a breakpoint in your `onCreate()` you can investigate the stack of calls that lead up to your `onCreate()` method. It is from that stack of calls that `savedInstanceState` originates. It can be different for different Android versions, but in my case on Android 10 that stack looks like this:

```
onCreate:183, MainPagerActivity (com.mydomain.android.activity)
performCreate:7802, Activity (android.app)
performCreate:7791, Activity (android.app)
callActivityOnCreate:1306, Instrumentation (android.app)
performLaunchActivity:3245, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleLaunchActivity:3409, ActivityThread (android.app)
execute:83, LaunchActivityItem (android.app.servertransaction)
executeCallbacks:135, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
execute:95, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
handleMessage:2016, ActivityThread$H (android.app)
dispatchMessage:107, Handler (android.os)
loop:214, Looper (android.os)
main:7356, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:492, RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:930, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

You can for example see that the code in the call chain is this (just move up the stack in the Android Studio debugger):

```
    private Activity performLaunchActivity(ActivityClientRecord r, Intent customIntent) {
```

and a bit further down:

```
                activity.mCalled = false;
                if (r.isPersistable()) {
                    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(activity, r.state, r.persistentState);
                } else {
                    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(activity, r.state);
                }
```

where `r.state` is the `savedInstanceState` you are passed. `ActivityClientRecord` holds lots of state for an `Activity`.

I could keep adding details to this mechanism, but hopefully it is enough to remove the "magic" of how you get a `savedInstanceState`.

Comment: Thanks very much man, this is exactly what I was looking for. I actually found the call > r.state = new Bundle(); inside the function > callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityClientRecord r) which indeed removes the "magic" for me. I am just so happy for finding the _new_ keyword. I can sleep happy now